# AWS EC2 - How to set up express server on my domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, server, load-balancing

I have an EC2 instance running an express server, and a load balancer to direct traffic. Of course, the server ip given to me by Amazon can't take https requests since I don't own it.

I have a custom domain set up for my website, and I want to use this https domain to process my express server calls as well. How do I go about doing this, without taking down my own website as well? I don't know where to start. Thank you.

Comment: Configure SSL on the load balancer should be all you need to do.

Comment: Also the 1:1 ration between SSL and IP addresses hasn't been a thing for a really long time. SNI solved that issue.

Comment: @jordanm You're a lifesaver. I'm a bit young to know that's been a solved problem, but that makes sense. Got it working, thanks a ton!